# Is it possible to handle switch parameters with Add-Member methods?

Tags: powershell, parameters, switch-statement

When adding a method to a PSObject using Add-Member is it possible to use [switch] parameters?

If so how does the syntax work when calling these methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only commands (functions, cmdlets) can have switches that work in the way you'd expect. If you assign a scriptblock as a method, any parameters that are declared as `[switch]` will be treated as if they are `[bool]`, accepting only `$true` or `$false`.